# Why Scala return in for-loop give Unit value type?

Tags: scala

I have written a for loop to traverse Map, I want this function return key immediately when found some value **(both of key and value is Int type)**

```
var hs:Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
for ((k,v) <- hs) {
  if (v == 1)
    return k   
}
```

but, scala give me the error message:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
  for ((k,v) <- hst)
             ^
one error found
```

then I change to

```
var result = 0
for ((k, v) <- hst){
  if (v == 1)
    result = k
}
result
```

then, it works well. Why the first version has type issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to return something if you function never enters in the if statement

```
def a() : Int = {
    var hs:Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
    for ((k,v) <- hs) {
        if (v == 1){
            return k
        }   
    }
    return -1
}
```

Comment: Generally, avoid return. In Scala, you'd never use return in the result position, at the end of the block.

Comment: Generally avoid using this ugly for loop I guess.... It's to show him his error, not to tell the best practices

Comment: You do see imperative loops with return in idiomatic code, for efficiency. The other interesting part is that return is typed Nothing, and the conditional is `if (c) ??? else ()` or `Unit`.

Answer (score 5):

The **compile error** is explained by @D.Peter, It's lack of a `return` for this **clause**.

In **Scala**, you can use [find](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IterableLike.html) to do that, like:

```
hs.find(_._2 == 1).map(_._1).getOrElse(0) // get or return default value.
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not very accurate because it's not about entering `if statement`, even if you remove `if` condition it will still not compile.

The problem is the for loop itself. Without `yield` it simply acts as a construct for *side effects*. Meaning it returns `Unit`. Pretty much like `foreach` semantics.

Read more [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/for-expressions.html).